# Как проверить эйлеровость графа? Содержит ли граф путь, проходящий через все ребра по 1 разу?

Tags: c++, олимпиада

**Задание:**

Дан неориентированный граф. Определить, содержит ли он путь, проходящий через все ребра ровно по 1 разу.

*Входные данные:*
Натуральное число n – количество вершин (1<=n<=1000).
Натуральное число m – количество ребер (1<=m<=1000).
m строк, каждая из которых содержит пару натуральных чисел - номеров вершин, соединенных ребрами (нумерация вершин с 1, между парой вершин может быть несколько ребер)

**Мои размышления:**

Путь, проходящий через все вершины ровно по 1 разу, называется [эйлеровым](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB), а [критерием](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2), существования такого пути являются два условия:

- в этом графе не больше 2 нечетных вершин
- все компоненты связанности, кроме, может быть, одной, не содержат ребер*.

Таким образом, все, что нужно сделать: в массив записать, сколько ребер приходит в каждую вершину; посчитать количество *нечетных* вершин и, если их больше 2, то выдать No, иначе Yes. Это первое условие.

**Мой код:**

```
int main () {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int num[n+1];
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) num[i] = 0;
    
    int a;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cin >> a;
            num[a]++;
        }
    }
    
    int oddNum = 0;
    bool answer = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (num[i] == 0) { answer = false; break; }
        else if (num[i] % 2 != 0) oddNum++;
        
    }
    if (answer) {
        if (oddNum > 2) answer = false;
        else answer = true;
    }
    cout << (answer ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

**Проблема в реализации 2-го условия:**

Мне не совсем понятно второе условие. Как его реализовать? Может быть, методом перебора, попробовав от каждой точки пробраться ко всем другим?

Comment: Второе условие фактически звучит как "граф связен". Проверить это условие можно, запустив bfs от какой-то вершины и проверив после этого, что все вершины графа были посещены. Bfs это как раз тот самый метод перебора, только оптимальный и работающий за размер графа.

Comment: Причем обходить вершины можно не отдельно, а проверять связность прямо по ходу работы - вершин не много, запросто массив достижимости построить...

Comment: @EzikBro Спасибо за BFS. Такая сложная формулировка условия давала мне некоторые сомнения того, что это просто значит "граф связен". Если вы дадите ответ, то я его приму. Если не хотите, ответ могу дать я сам

Comment: Как оказалось, формулировка второго условия обозначает не совсем "граф связен", а несколько другое. См. ответ EzikBro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сейчас понял, что в своем комментарии я на самом деле ошибся. Если, например задан граф из 10 вершин, где 8 из них связаны подряд ребрами 1-2, 2-3, ..., 7-8, а оставшиеся две вершины ребер не имеют, то граф не связный, однако он имеет эйлеров путь.

То есть нужно посчитать кол-во тех компонент связности, которые **содержат ребра**, и убедиться, что таких **не больше**  1.

Чтобы сделать это нужно составить реальный граф и попытаться запустить bfs из каждой вершины:

```
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;
vector<vector<int>> g(n); // список инцидентных ребер каждой вершины
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    int u, v;
    cin >> u >> v;
    g[u - 1].push_back(v - 1);
    g[v - 1].push_back(u - 1);
}

// Проверка нечетности
int count_odd = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (g[i].size() % 2 == 1)
        count_odd++;

// Подсчет количества "больших" компонент
int count_big_comp = 0;
vector<bool> use(n, false); // хранит состояния "посещенности" для всех вершин

// Перебор всех вершин для нахождения всех компонент
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (use[i]) // Проверка вершины на посещенность в какой-то из прошлых компонент
        continue;
    if (g[i].size() == 0) // Проверка вершины на изолированность
        // Вообще тут по логике должна быть строка use[i] = true, но ее можно опустить
        continue;

    count_big_comp++;

    // bfs от i-той вершины
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(i);
    use[i] = true;
    
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int v = q.front();
        q.pop();
        
        for (int to : g[v])
        {
            if (use[to])
                continue;
            q.push(to);
            use[to] = true;
        }
    }
}

if (count_odd <= 2 && count_big_comp <= 1)
    cout << "YES\n";
else
    cout << "NO\n";
```

Comment: Я исправил свой вопрос, чтобы он был только об эйлеровости графа, а не о возможности нарисовать его без отрыва руки, так как это не тождественно: для эйлеровости требуется, чтобы граф имел не более одной компоненты связности, **содержащей ребра**; а для рисования без отрыва руки -- чтобы граф имел не более одной компоненты связности **вообще**. Поэтому сошлюсь здесь, в комментарии, к первой версии вопроса и отмечу, что, чтобы граф можно было нарисовать без отрыва руки,  второе условие должно быть строже: 2) граф содержит **ровно** 1 компоненту связности, проще говоря, **является связным.**